# Adding OIDC to an React application with restricted routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, react-context

I want to add OIDC to my React application and I am using [oidc-client-ts](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src%2FApp.tsx) since it seems popular and is still being maintained. My problem is that I miss some React examples.

What I want is all but one routes to be protected. If the user is not authenticated, they should be redirected to the login screen which has a button to activate the auth-flow using a custom provider.

I have tried to use [these](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src%2FApp.tsx) [two](https://github.com/authts/sample-angular-oidc-client-ts) examples, but I am unsure how to glue them together and how to convert the Angular code to React.

So far I have wrapped the entire application in an AuthContext and made all but one route private as in the [first example](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src%2FApp.tsx):

**index.tsx:**

```
<StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={routes.LOGIN} element={<LoginContainer />} />
                <Route element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route index element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/openid/callback" element={<AuthCallback />} />
                        // Other pages
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
</StrictMode>
```

The `Layout`-component with a private route, to make all paths but `"/login"` private:

```
function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
    const auth = useAuth();

    if (!auth.user) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
    }

    return children;
}

function Layout() {
    return (
        <RequireAuth>
            <>
                <Header />
                <Main />
                <Footer />
            </>
        </RequireAuth>
    );
}
```

**AuthProvider:**

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null!);

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
    const authService = new AuthService();

    const login = () => authService.login().then(user1 => setUser(user1));

    const loginCallback = async () => {
        const authedUser = await authService.loginCallback();
        setUser(authedUser);
    };

    const logout = () => authService.login().then(() => setUser(null));
    const value = { user, login, logout };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

The `authService` is just copied from the [angular example](https://github.com/authts/sample-angular-oidc-client-ts/blob/main/src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts):

```
import { User, UserManager } from "oidc-client-ts";

export default class AuthService {
    userManager: UserManager;

    constructor() {
        const settings = {
            authority: "...",
            client_id: "...",
            redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/openid/callback",
            client_secret: "...",
            post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/login"
        };
        this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
    }

    public getUser(): Promise<User | null> {
        return this.userManager.getUser();
    }

    public login(): Promise<void> {
        return this.userManager.signinRedirect();
    }

    public loginCallback(): Promise<User> {
        return this.userManager.signinRedirectCallback();
    }

    public logout(): Promise<void> {
        return this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
    }
}
```

My issue is that I do not know how to set the user in the `AuthProvider` so I can check if I am auth'ed in the `RequireAuth`-component. It is not set in my `then` in the `AuthProvider`s login and logout functions, so I just get redirected to the login-page whenever I try to login.

Can someone tell me how I can make the authentication flow using OIDC and restrict all my paths but one to authenticated users only?

Furthermore [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59370777/7925759) says that there should be an `AuthorizationCallback`-component to parse the URL. When I use [oidc-client-ts](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src%2FApp.tsx) which seems to parse the data for me, do I really need this extra step or can I just have the redirect URL be "/" or "/home"?

**Edit:**

I found out that `signinRedirect` goes to a new URL which means that the rest of the script is never run. `signinRedirectCallback` is the call that returns the user. I will post it as an answer when I have figured out how to protect the routes properly. The check in `RequireAuth` is done before the user is set. How do I postpone the check until the user has been set so I do not redirect to login even though I am signed in? And if I refresh the page I lose the `user` state from `AuthProvider` and I will be sent to the login page even though there is an active session. I am unsure where and how I check if I have a session running when I load the app in a clean way.

Comment: What is the value of `user1` in the `login` handler where you are trying to update the `user` state? How do you know the `useState` isn't updated? It seems highly unlikely that React state updates aren't working.

Comment: I have tried to log `user1`, but I never get to the `then`-part. I think `signinRedirect` in the `authService` is the issue. It doesn't seem to come back to the `login`-call from the `AuthProvider`.

Comment: Can you share your `authService` code then so we can see what it's doing and returning in these methods?

Comment: I have updated the question so it includes the `authService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it with inspiration from Drew Reese's answer.
The thing is that [oidc-client-ts](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts)' `signinRedirect` will redirect to the authentication server and thus the React code will stop it's execution and the `then` block is never run. The trick is to use [signinRedirectCallback](https://authts.github.io/oidc-client-ts/classes/UserManager.html#signinRedirectCallback) which `processes the response from the authorization endpoint` after the login-call. So when I hit the redirect url (`http://localhost:3000/openid/callback`), I call the `signinRedirectCallback` to find out if I should go to the `Home` or `Login`-component. So all routes but`/login` and the post-login-redirect-url will be auth-protected:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path={routes.LOGIN} element={<LoginContainer />} />
  <Route path="/openid/callback" element={<AuthCallback />} />
  <Route element={<LayoutWithAuth />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    ...
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
</Routes>;
```

Then on the redirect back to the app, `loginCallback/signingRedirectCallback` (the first is  just forwarding the call to the `authService`), sets the user in the `AuthContext` (see it below) and I navigate to the home page:

**AuthCallback:**

```js
function AuthCallback() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.loginCallback().then(() => {
      navigate(routes.INDEX);
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>Processing signin...</div>;
}
```

By making `loginCallback` async, I make sure than when I redirect to the login page, the user will be set when the `LayoutWithAuth`-component does the auth-check:

```js
function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return auth.user === undefined ? <Navigate to="/login" replace /> : children;
}

function LayoutWithAuth() {
  return (
    <RequireAuth>
      <>
        <Header />
        <Body />
        <Footer />
      </>
    </RequireAuth>
  );
}
```

`oidc-client-ts` saves the user in the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), so if the page is refreshed, the `AuthContext` will first check the sessionStorage to see if the user is auth'ed:

**AuthContext:**

```js
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null!);

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null | undefined>(
    JSON.parse(
      sessionStorage.getItem(process.env.REACT_APP_SESSION_ID!) || "null"
    ) || undefined
  );

  const authService = new AuthService();

  const loginCallback = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const authedUser = await authService.loginCallback();
    setUser(authedUser);
  };

  // Login and logout methods

  const value = { user, login, logout };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

**Update:**
Adding the `LoginContainer`:

```js
function LoginContainer() {
  const auth = useAuth();

  const login = () => {
    auth.login();
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <Headline>Some headline</Headline>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => login()}>
        {texts.BUTTON_LOGIN}
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default LoginContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `login` utility only returns a resolved `Promise<void>`, no user value, so while you *can* chain from the returned Promise there is no resolved value returned in the chain.

```
public login(): Promise<void> {
  return this.userManager.signinRedirect();
}
```

## Solution

After a successful authentication it seems you must call `getUser` to get the current user value, a `User` object or null.

```
public getUser(): Promise<User | null> {
  return this.userManager.getUser();
}
```

Here's a `login` implementation that gets the user after logging in.

```
function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const authService = new AuthService();

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await authService.login();
      const user = await authService.getUser();
      setUser(user);
    } catch(error) {
      // log error, set error state, ignore, etc...
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    try {
      await authService.logout();
    } catch(error) {
      // log error, set error state, ignore, etc...
    } finally {
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  const value = { user, login, logout };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You could, of course, update your `AuthService` to return the authenticated user directly.

```
export default class AuthService {
  ...

  public login(): Promise<User | null> {
    return this.userManager.signinRedirect()
      .then(getUser)
      .catch(error => {
        // handle any errors, rejected Promises, etc...
        return null;
      });
  }

  // or

  public async login(): Promise<User | null> {
    try {
      await this.userManager.signinRedirect();
      return getUser();
    } catch(error) {
      // handle any errors, rejected Promises, etc...
      return null;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Now the original `AuthContext` `login` function will work as expected.

```
const login = () => authService.login()
  .then(user1 => setUser(user1))
  .catch((error) => {
    // log error, set error state, ignore, etc...
    setUser(null);
  });
```

or

```
  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await authService.login();
      setUser(user);
    } catch(error) {
      // log error, set error state, ignore, etc...
      setUser(null);
    }
  };
```

### Updates

> The check in `RequireAuth` is done before the user is set. How do I
> postpone the check until the user has been set so I do not redirect to
> login even though I am signed in?

For this you can use a sort of "loading" state. I usually suggest either added an explicit loading state or using an initial `auth` state value that doesn't match either the authenticated or unauthenticated state.

For example, if `null` is the unauthenticated user, and some user object is an authenticated user, use an `undefined` initial value.

Auth context

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<any>();
```

...

```
function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return auth.user ? children : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

> And if I refresh the page I lose the user state from AuthProvider and
> I will be sent to the login page even though there is an active
> session.

This is because when the page is reloaded, the entire app is remounted. Any local component state is lost. You can try initializing/persisting state to localStorage.

Example:

```
function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || undefined
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }, [user]);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because `signinRedirect` leaves the page and thus the rest of the script is not run. I think I have fixed this part, but I still have issues with checking the session and protecting routes. I have updated my question with some more details.

Comment: @Kikkomann Ok, I saw your edit and updated my answer to address at least the questions regarding the route protection and auth state persistence. I don't know what `signinRedirectCallback` is though. Are you saying this function correctly redirects back to your app with the user object, and this is working?

Comment: It works all fine. Two things though: I know I set my `user` object to be of type any, but I want it to be of type `User | null`, but then I get issues with using undefined. My `value` in `AuthProvider` complains about a type mismatch. How do I fix this? The other thing is that the `UserManager` (https://authts.github.io/oidc-client-ts/classes/UserManager.html) already keeps track of the session state in the app. If I start using `localStorage` manually, isn't it just doing the same things two times? The nice thing is that localStorage is not async.

Comment: @Kikkomann You can probably include undefined, i.e. `useState<User | null | undefined>(.....)`. I don't follow your other question about localStorage and doing something twice. Can you clarify?

Comment: Ah I forgot to add it on the interface type for `AuthContext`.
`AuthService` uses the `UserManager` (from `oidc-client-ts`) which creates and manages the `sessionStorage`. The thing is that `authService.getUser()` is an async function, which is what gives me problems to check if I am logged in on a page reload. When I use `localStorage` it works, but then I have the user object stored in two places: `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. I could perhaps just save a flag in the local storage, but the user user is still managed in two locations. I hope that was more clear.

Comment: @Kikkomann Oh, I see. Does just using the sessionStorage work for persisting component state?

Comment: Oh wow, since I have not used sessionStorage before, I didn't even think about using it for the check. It sounds like that is the trick. I will get back if it doesn't work or add a solution/accept your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244681/discussion-between-kikkomann-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @Kikkomann Your above answers helped a lot. What is your login container look like? Also, my RequireAuth function is getting called twice. Could you please help with that

Comment: @DSR Are you asking a question specific to code you are using? You might consider asking it as a new post. You can reference this question/answer if it helps clarify your specific issue. If you do post a new question feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: @DrewReese As I checked, it is a valid behaviour in React.StrictMode. The problem is, due to React.StrictMode double render, signinRedirectCallback is getting called two times and getting error - **Uncaught (in promise) Error: No matching state found in storage
    at OidcClient.readSigninResponseState (OidcClient.ts:148:1)
    at async OidcClient.processSigninResponse (OidcClient.ts:159:1)
    at async UserManager._signinEnd (UserManager.ts:402:1)
    at async UserManager.signinRedirectCallback (UserManager.ts:163:1)
    at async Object.loginCallback (App.tsx:93:1)**

Comment: @DSR Sounds like you might have an unexpected/unintentional side-effect then.

Comment: @DSR I have added the `LoginContainer` and as Drew Reese, I will suggest that you post a new question for your issue.

Comment: I am trying to implement Auth in my app using oidc-client-ts with an Auth service and a provider but I am dealing with the same issue that was mentioned in this post. After authentication, I don't get the user. So I modified my login function just like suggested in this post  to call getUser after signinRedirect but still I'm getting back the user or seeing it in sessionStorage. Any idea what I cold be doing wrong?

Comment: How did you guys update the user after a silentRenew updated the accesstoken?